# Error when using roman numerals in section heading LaTex

Tags: latex, roman-numerals

I want to use roman numerals to enumerate some sections in my latex document.

I use this: `\MakeUppercase{\romannumeral 2}` to create the numeral. This works fine in the normal text but if I try to use it in a **section** or **subsection** command I get an  "*undefined control sequence*" error even though it seems to display the numeral correctly in the section heading.

Apparently the problem is with the `\MakeUppercase` command, as just the `\romannumeral 2` command does not give an error.

I have also tried to define a `\newcommand` with the same effect.

Does anybody have an idea why that is the case?

Edit: after creating a minimal reproducible example I figured out that the problem has something to do with the `hyperref` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\RomanNumeralCaps}[1]{\MakeUppercase{\romannumeral #1}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Some chapter}
\section{Some section}
\subsection{Experiment \MakeUppercase{\romannumeral 1}}
\MakeUppercase{\romannumeral 1}
\RomanNumeralCaps{2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make a [mre] which we can compile to reproduce your problem and not just such code fragments

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out it already helped narrow down the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide an alternative string for the pdf bookmark:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{romannum}% for approach #1 and #2
\usepackage{biblatex}% for approach #3
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Some chapter}
\section{Some section}
\subsection{Experiment \texorpdfstring{\Romannum{1}}{I}}

or

\subsection[Experiment II]{Experiment \Romannum{2}}

or

\subsection{Experiment \RN{3}}

However with this approach the III will be replaced by 3 in the pdf bookmarks

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks this works. For completion sake here is the issue with `hyperref` solved in the same way [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249107/how-to-use-texorpdfstring-characters-disappear]